# Run entire notebook

Tags: function-construction, notebooks

I have created a notebook, with functions. The only thing that I want to change in the notebook later is the input file. I therefor want to have a button that runs every input step-by-step so that I do not have to go into every input and press enter for it to update. How could this be done.

Comment: If you're using Windows, why not CTRL+A and then SHIFT+ENTER ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing is to command-A and enter, which selects all the cells and evaluates. Or you can use a button

```
evalStart := Module[{}, 
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "EvaluateInitialization"]];
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectAll"]];
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "EvaluateCells"]];];
Button["do it", evalStart]
```

When you evaluate this, a button appears. Every time you press the button, it evaluates everything by first evaluating the initialization cells (if any), then selecting all, then evaluating all the cells.

[image]

Comment: Why not to simply use the `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "EvaluateNotebook"]]`? Anyway, good solution!

Answer (score 8):

There is a [`Evaluation -> Evaluate Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/EvaluateNotebook.html) menu for that.

Or, you can set some cells to have [`Initialization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionsForCells.html) property ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/WorkWithInitializationCells.html) on usage).

Comment: Since he/she asked for a button, the other answer is "better" but you are totally right: There's a simple menu function for that.

Comment: "Evaluate Notebook" is now called "Evaluate All Cells"